# How to send SMS to a PHP array with Twilio API

Tags: php, arrays, sms, twilio-php

Using the Twilio API, I've got my PHP functioning to send to one phone number, and can successfully send. We're looking to send to multiple numbers from one request and to do so, I've set up an array of numbers to iterate through, however, I keep getting a 500 error when I attempt to send the message by hitting the URL. Below is the file I'm working with.

Running PHP 7.2 on a Linux server. I'm running CentOS 7.7 and Apache 2.4.43 if that matters at all.

```
// Require the bundled autoload file - the path may need to change
// based on where you downloaded and unzipped the SDK
require __DIR__ . '/twilio-php-master/src/Twilio/autoload.php';

// Use the REST API Client to make requests to the Twilio REST API
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$sid = 'XXXXXXXX';
$token = 'XXXXXXXX';
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

$a = array('+15555555555', '+15555555556');

$bodyTxt = “This is a test of sending the text message to multiple phone numbers.”
// Use the client to do fun stuff like send text messages!

foreach ($a as $v) {
    $message = $twilio->messages
        $client->messages->create($v, // to
                           [
                               "body" => $bodyTxt,
                               "from" => "+15555555557",
                           ]
                  );
        print($message->sid);
}
);
```

I'm not super familiar with PHP as I'm mostly in marketing, but I'm deputizing as developer in these crazy times because I know just enough to be dangerous. I'm thinking it is something with the foreach section, as that's the only piece that has changed from the single send.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: to be clear, if your $a array is just  array('+15555555555'), it does work? (using the foreach with only one element), I think you are also missing a ; on the first line of your foreach. The api clearly says you can do what you are doing (for loop calls with no delay), may I have more detail on the error? full message edited into your answer may help me with your issue.

Comment: Can I have more info on "does not work"? message displayed? blank screen? dumps with exits in some parts of the code?

Comment: @LuisE - Just tested and it does not work with only one number in the array either. It works for one number when I use Twilio's basic PHP setup in their guides. The missing semicolon makes sense. Would that go after the ) before the {

The message body is literally what you see there, we're just running a test to ensure it works properly before delivering to their audience.

The error I get is a 500 error, "domain.com is currently unable to handle this request." There's no error in the Twilio logs.

Thanks!

Comment: @LuisE - any thoughts on the above? Single number doesn't work with the array, but using Twilio's basic PHP setup works with one number. Do you have an idea where would the missing semicolon would go? The message body is literally what you see there, we're just running a test to ensure it works properly before delivering to their audience. The error I get is a 500 error, "domain.com is currently unable to handle this request." There's no error in the Twilio logs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out thanks to the help from @LuisE! I went through and figured out where I was missing the semicolons after the array, the $bodyTxt, and the $message = $twilio->messages.

```
// Require the bundled autoload file - the path may need to change
// based on where you downloaded and unzipped the SDK
require __DIR__ . '/twilio-php-master/src/Twilio/autoload.php';

// Use the REST API Client to make requests to the Twilio REST API
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$sid = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
$token = 'XXXXXXXXX';
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

$a = array('+15555555555', '+15555555556');

$bodyTxt = 'This is a test of sending the text message to multiple phone numbers.';
// Use the client to do fun stuff like send text messages!

foreach ($a as $v) {
    $message = $twilio->messages;
        $client->messages->create($v, // to
                           [
                               "body" => $bodyTxt,
                               "from" => "+15555555557",
                           ]
                  );
        print($message->sid);
}
```

Comment: I am very glad to know, I did nothing at all c: